# Selecting a form by name, not id using mechanicalsoup

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

Even after reading some docs, I am still having trouble understanding what mechanical soup's stateful browser's `select_form()` does. Does it take an ID or does it take a name? The form that I am using does not have an id, but a name. Will using `select_form()` take an ID or a name? The form I am trying to use looks like this (no ID).

```
<div class="fsLoginForms">
    <div id="fsLoginForm" class="fsLogin" >
        <form name="userlogin" action="" method="post">

            <p class="fsLoginTitle">Site Login</p>
            <p class="fsLoginMessage">Please provide your username and password to log in:</p>

            <label for="username">username</label><input type="text" class="fsLoginUser" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" maxlength="50" value=""><br>
            <label for="password">password</label><input type="password" class="fsLoginPass" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" maxlength="50" value="" ><br>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using

`stateful_browser.select_form("#userlogin")`

and

`stateful_browser.select_form("userlogin")`

It keeps throwing this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loginScrape.py", line 25, in <module>
    browser.select_form('#userlogin')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mechanicalsoup/stateful_browser.py", line 175, in select_form
    raise LinkNotFoundError()
mechanicalsoup.utils.LinkNotFoundError
```

UPDATE: I tried authenticating into that website with incorrect credentials and I got the same error. I'm not too sure what this means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs at http://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html?highlight=select_form#mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser.select_form

you should be able to use no arguments to get a form, if it is the only form on the page.

Alternatively, use CSS selectors:

```
stateful_browser.select_form('form[name="userlogin"]')
```

Details of CSS selectors at: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: Thanks so much. The CSS selectors are what ended up working for me